# MFC MDI Designing user preferences dialog GUI layout functionality

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2017, mfc, mdi

In this instance I am not "stuck" but looking for some 'guidance' on how to perform a GUI layout mechanism that makes sense and easy to construct. I am using a `TreeControl` that visually "matches" Winamp's options/preferences dialog for all the settings and program options.

TO BE CLEAR: This is not something I've ever attempted and looking for user input to help me get across the finish line.

I have 6 items in the 'tree' (the 'parent') and 5 'subitems'. I have it fully constructed and I can get the data from whatever node is selected (which I'll post below images).

I am using a "do.Modal dialog" and, when I click on the tree node, I want the right side of the dialog to update to the needed controls for that node function. The execution of controls through "show" and "hide" to me seems pretty easy. The issue I have is the how to do the visual "static" controls in the resource editor when each "node paged" controls may or may not sit on top of each other visually during `design time`. During run time, when each node is selected on the nodes controls will be active but during design time, I may have controls sitting on top of each other and will be a logistical nightmare trying to sort out their positions etc.

How do I resolve that aspect of building it? I think of it as a select: 'node' show: 'option page controls' so I get the logic; I'm just wondering if I should have separate "popup" pages and call those … or deal with the controls directly. Does that makes sense?

I've done some searching on how to do this, but the examples are all over the place and I figured asking here makes the most sense. I'm sure there are multiple ways to do this, I'm just looking for the shortest path and easiest to maintain and possibly expand on the options in the future.

The examples of the dialog and the source code I'm using:

[image: My Settings Dialog]

[image: Winamp's User Preferences Dialog]

Here is the initialization code:

```
BOOL CSettingsDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here

    HTREEITEM hParent, hToolbars, hColorScheme, hTabStyles, hPowerUser,
        hResetApp;
                
    //HTREEITEM hCompany, hLevel, hLevelNext; // Used in core example, not needed here

    hParent = m_TreeCtrl.InsertItem((L"Preferences"), TVI_ROOT);
    hToolbars = m_TreeCtrl.InsertItem((L"Toolbars"), hParent);
    hColorScheme = m_TreeCtrl.InsertItem((L"Color Scheme"), hParent);
    hTabStyles = m_TreeCtrl.InsertItem((L"Tab Styles"), hParent);
    hPowerUser = m_TreeCtrl.InsertItem((L"Power User"), hParent);   
    hResetApp= m_TreeCtrl.InsertItem((L"Reset All Options"), hParent);
    
    m_TreeCtrl.Expand(hParent, TVE_EXPAND);
    m_TreeCtrl.SelectItem(hParent);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_SETTINGS_CAPTION)->SetWindowText(_T("Preferences Settings"));

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Here is the dialog framework that I'm starting from scratch with just to arrive here:

```
void CSettingsDlg::OnTvnSelchangedTree1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{

    //LPNMTREEVIEW pNMTreeView = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTREEVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    //SetDlgItemInt(IDC_TXT_TREE1, m_TreeCtrl.GetItemData(pNMTreeView->itemNew.hItem));
    //*pResult = 0;

    HTREEITEM sel = m_TreeCtrl.GetSelectedItem();
    CPoint point;
    CString str;
    GetCursorPos(&point);
    m_TreeCtrl.ScreenToClient(&point);
    UINT flags = 0;
    HTREEITEM hitItem = m_TreeCtrl.HitTest(point, &flags);
    if (hitItem && sel != hitItem)
    {
        sel = hitItem;
        m_TreeCtrl.SelectItem(sel);     
        str = m_TreeCtrl.GetItemText(sel);
        //MessageBox((LPCTSTR)str);  // Just to verify.  
    }

    if (str == "Preferences")
    {
        this->SetWindowText(_T("Preferences Settings"));
        GetDlgItem(IDC_SETTINGS_CAPTION)->SetWindowText(_T("Preferences Settings"));
    }

    if (str == "Toolbars")
    {
        this->SetWindowText(_T("Toolbars Settings"));
        GetDlgItem(IDC_SETTINGS_CAPTION)->SetWindowText(_T("Toolbars Settings"));
    }

    if (str == "Color Scheme")
    {
        this->SetWindowText(_T("Color Scheme"));
        GetDlgItem(IDC_SETTINGS_CAPTION)->SetWindowText(_T("Color Scheme Settings"));
    }

    if (str == "Tab Styles")
    {
        this->SetWindowText(_T("Tab Styles Settings"));
        GetDlgItem(IDC_SETTINGS_CAPTION)->SetWindowText(_T("Tab Styles Settings"));
    }

    if (str == "Power User")
    {
        this->SetWindowText(_T("Power User Settings"));
        GetDlgItem(IDC_SETTINGS_CAPTION)->SetWindowText(_T("Power User Settings"));
    }

    if (str == "Reset All Options")
    {
        this->SetWindowText(_T("Reset All Settings"));
        GetDlgItem(IDC_SETTINGS_CAPTION)->SetWindowText(_T("Reset All Settings"));
    }
    
    *pResult = 0;

}
```

So as shown, you can see that I have the ability to change the static caption to the "active" page node that is selected from the tree. I'm looking to solve the best way to handle the GUI elements that will go on the right side....

Some controls for example will be:

```
Color scheme Node: 5 check boxes for theme changing

Toolbars Node: Radio button for Docked or Floating

Power User Node: Checkbox to disable user warning within program operation

Tab Styles Node: Radio buttons to select flat, 3d, whatever.
```

and when the user "selects" whatever it writes it to the registry and then I call the function to read the data blah blah blah...

So that is where I'm at. Does anyone have any suggestions on a course of action, so I don't paint myself into a corner?

Comment: You are looking for a [CDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I can't actually speak for how the authors of the "Winamp" software implemented their UI, I would suggest that you consider using a [property sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/property-sheets) for your case, where each set of controls can be implemented as separate *property pages*, each of which will be defined (both in the resource script and in the C++ code) in ways very similar to individual modal dialog boxes.

The 'classic' property sheet has a horizontal row of tabs (normally, at the top of the sheet) to select each page, as shown in the sample below. Indeed, some sources/platforms refer to a property sheet as a "tabbed dialog".

[image]

However, the new(ish) [`CMFCPropertySheet` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpropertysheet-class?view=msvc-160) allows you to replace that tab control with one of several other options, which will show as separate 'panes' (on the left-hand side of the sheet). To use one of these alternative styles, call the [`SetLook()` member function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpropertysheet-class?view=msvc-160#setlook) in your constructor override with the `CMFCPropertySheet::PropSheetLook_Tree` enum value. The [example shown in the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/media/proptree.png?view=msvc-160) is not *exactly* what you have shown in your question, but the `CMFCPropertySheet` and `CMFCPropertyPage` classes allow many, many customizations to their appearance and style.

I have never actually used the `PropSheetLook_Tree` style, but the image below shows "one I made earlier" with the `PropSheetLook_OutlookBar` style.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that detailed feedback Adrian, the `example shown in the link` is a good alternative and close to what I want. Since the original code (not mine) didn't have this feature at all, I am trying to find the framework code to build that linked dialog you showed. Is there a wizard in `VS2017` that can construct it, or am I trying to rewrite what I have to support that new dialog type? It would be helpful if I could work from some template/example if there is one to be had and I can adapt it. Thanks for any added info.

Comment: I can't find a VS Wizard right now, but here's a tutorial that may help: http://www.functionx.com/visualc/dialogboxes/mfcpspp.htm

Comment: I started the tutorial brand new. Everything went fine right up until the first compile. VS has multiple errors on the `enum` being used for the property pages. `enum { IDD = IDD_CAREERS };`  `enum { IDD = IDD_COMPUTERSCIENCE };` ... there are 5 of those...all come up with C2065. I followed the tut verbatim minus one thing where they say `Access the Careers.h file and change it as follows` where it should be `Careers.cpp`. I'm stuck there as I can't figure out what is exactly wrong.

Comment: @Kittmaster Not sure why VS doesn't do it for you, but you should add `#include "Resource.h"` (or something very similar) to your precompiled header file (the pch.h file, or possibly stdafx.h in VS before 2019).

Comment: I had to add `Stdafx.h` manually because the tutorial doesn't mention it, but expects it to be there...I do recall seeing a `resource.h`, I'll double check in the morning. `pch.h` is present, but I will double check to be sure.

Comment: This is turning out to be a waste of time. There is a `resource.h` etc. I added `#include "resource.h"` solving unknowns. I had to add destructors those were missing, now I get linker errors like `LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct AFX_MSGMAP const * __thiscall CCareers::GetMessageMap(void)const " (?GetMessageMap@CCareers@@MBEPBUAFX_MSGMAP@@XZ) LifePlanning C:\Users\\Desktop\Tutorial\LifePlanning\LifePlanning\CCareers.obj`

Comment: @Kittmaster Yeah. There seems to be quite a few errors in that tutorial. I managed to get to the first runnable, but I had to add lots of missing destructors, messages maps and `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` lines in many of the cpp files. The missing message maps and the dynamic implementers can be copied from files that have them and modified to have the correct class names. It's not too much work, actually.

Comment: ... or you can maybe comment-out the `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP` and `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` lines on the headers for those classes that don't have them or need them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231459/discussion-between-kittmaster-and-adrian-mole).

Comment: It took me quite a bit..but I finally got this sorted out...between Adrian's pointers on how to do it, with some help on the erroneous tutorial...I was able to get my code working. Thanks for all the help!